# How to customize python installation in both normal and develop mode? (Why `setuptools.command.develop` is not called in develop/editable mode?)

Tags: cmake, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, pep517

I am building a `example_package` on which I would like to customize the installing process in both `normal` and `develop` mode. Here is the project structure:

```
.
├── cpp
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── helloworld.cpp
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── example_package
        └── __init__.py
```

### The content of each file is shown below

- `pyproject.toml`: A minimum information is added.

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=62.0.0", "wheel", "cmake>=3.20"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "example_package"
version = "0.0.1"
requires-python = ">=3.8"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

- `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command import develop, build_py, install
import subprocess

class CustomDevelop(develop.develop):
    def run(self):
        super(CustomDevelop, self).run()
        print("Execute CustomDevelop ......")

class CustomBuildPy(build_py.build_py):
    def run(self):
        super(CustomBuildPy, self).run()
        print("Execute CustomBuildPy ......")

class CustomInstall(install.install):
    def run(self):
        super(CustomInstall, self).run()
        print("Execute CustomInstall ......")
        
setup(
    cmdclass={
        'develop': CustomDevelop,
        'build_py': CustomBuildPy,
        'install': CustomInstall
    }
)
```

### Installation

#### Normal mode

- Create, activate `venv`, and update `pip` and `setuptools`:

  ```
  python3 -m venv venv/ && source venv/bin/activate && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
  ```
- Install in `normal` mode:

  ```
  python3 -m pip install -vv . 2>&1 | grep -E "running|Execute"
  ```
- The output message:

```
  running egg_info
  running dist_info
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  running egg_info
  Execute CustomBuildPy ......
  running install
  running install_lib
  running install_egg_info
  running install_scripts
  Execute CustomInstall ......
```

which is expected. `CustomBuildPy` and `CustomInstall` were executed.

#### Develop mode

- Create, activate `venv`, and update `pip` and `setuptools`:

  ```
  python3 -m venv venv/ && source venv/bin/activate && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
  ```
- Install in `develop` mode:

  ```
  python3 -m pip install -vv -e . 2>&1 | grep -E "running|Execute"
  ```
- The output message:

```
  running egg_info
  running dist_info
  running editable_wheel
  running build_py
  Execute CustomBuildPy ......
  running egg_info
```

which is not expected by me,  because only `CustomBuildPy` is run but not `CustomDevelop`.

### What I really want to do

The reason that I need to execute the costumed command in the installing process in the normal and develop mode is that I have a `helloworld.cpp` which needs to be compiled into a executable `helloworld` and put into the `sys.path`.

- `cpp/helloworld.cpp`: For example, the content of `helloworld.cpp` is trivial:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << "Hello World!!!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

- `cpp/CMakeLists.txt`: the associated `CMakeLists.txt` is also trivial:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(HelloWorld)
add_executable(helloworld helloworld.cpp)
```

The executable `helloworld` can be run in the module `example_package` like below:

```
$ cat src/example_package/__init__.py 
import subprocess, os, sysconfig, sys
src_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
os.environ['PATH'] = src_dir + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
subprocess.run("helloworld", env=os.environ)
```

Lastly, I change the `CustomBuildPy` to:

```
class CustomBuildPy(build_py.build_py):
    def run(self):
        super(CustomBuildPy, self).run()
        print("Execute CustomBuildPy ......")
        subprocess.check_call("cmake -S cpp/ -B cpp/cmakebuild && cmake --build cpp/cmakebuild", shell=True)
        subprocess.check_call("cp cpp/cmakebuild/helloworld build/lib/.", shell=True)
```

When installing in normal mode, everything works great. The executable `helloworld` appears in `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.
But when installing in develop mode, the error emerges:

```
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cp -r cpp/build/helloworld build/lib/.' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Because the `build` folder is not created in the develop mode in the source folder `.`.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: It is not a necessity to move the full setuptools configuration from `setup.py` to `pyproject.toml` and delete the `setup.py` script. As far as I know, it is possible to keep a `setup.py` script just for the custom command, while everything else is in `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: I think you should look into using [*scikit-build-core*](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-build-core/) instead of just *setuptools*. *scikit-build-core* is specially conceived to package Python projects with *CMake*.

Comment: But maybe you can make it so that your custom `build_py` creates the `build` directory, I do not think there is anything against this.

Answer (score 0):

I still can not figure out why `setuptools.command.develop` is not called in `develop` mode. But I find out the solution to achieve what I want to do: make the executable `helloworld` appear in the `sys.path` correctly in both `normal` and `develop` mode.
The key is to maintain the relative path between the executable `helloworld` and the package `example_package`. So, the module in `example_package` can always add the relative path between `helloworld` and `example_package` into `os.environ['PATH']` in both `normal` and `develop` mode.

### Minimal reproducible example

Firstly, change `CustomBuildPy` to the following:

```py
class CustomBuildPy(build_py.build_py):
    def run(self):
        super(CustomBuildPy, self).run()
        print("Execute CustomBuildPy ......")
        subprocess.check_call("cmake -S cpp/ -B cpp/cmakebuild && cmake --build cpp/cmakebuild", shell=True)

        # Copying `helloworld` to `src/.` doesn't make sense in normal mode, but it doesn't hurt.
        subprocess.check_call("cp cpp/cmakebuild/helloworld src/.", shell=True)
        
        # Copying `helloworld` to `build/lib/.` makes `helloworld` appear in venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
        # in normal mode. This line doesn't work in develop mode. But again, it doesn't hurt.
        subprocess.check_call("cp cpp/cmakebuild/helloworld build/lib/.", shell=True)
```

- `subprocess.check_call("cp cpp/cmakebuild/helloworld src/.", shell=True)` works in `develop` mode.
- `subprocess.check_call("cp cpp/cmakebuild/helloworld build/lib/.", shell=True)` works in `normal` mode.

#### Pip Install in `normal` mode

- Create, activate `venv`, and update `pip` and `setuptools`:

  ```
  python3 -m venv venv/ && source venv/bin/activate && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
  ```
- Install in `normal` mode:

  ```
  python3 -m pip install .
  ```
- Verify installation:

```
>>> import example_package
Hello World!!!
```

#### Pip Install in `develop` mode

- Create, activate `venv`, and update `pip` and `setuptools`:

  ```
  python3 -m venv venv/ && source venv/bin/activate && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
  ```
- Install in `develop` mode:

  ```
  python3 -m pip install -e .
  ```
- Verify installation:

```
>>> import example_package
Hello World!!!
```

Comment: As far as I know *pip* does not call the *develop* and *install* commands of `setup.py`, because it does not need to. -- It seems to me like there are better ways to implement this, there seems to be some useful points in this [documentation page](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/extension.html#supporting-sdists-and-editable-installs-in-build-sub-commands). -- If I were you I would also experiment with the `scripts` parameter of `setuptools.setup()` function, to hopefully ensure that the `helloworld` executable is installed and uninstalled in the correct location.